# Operation results in exceeding quota limits of Core. Maximum allowed: 4, Current in use: 0, Additional requested: 6

Tags: sql-server, azure, sharepoint

I'm trying to create a free account and start using the **SharePoint 2013 non-HA Farm** VM in Microsoft Azure.

But I'm facing the following error as I'm going through the registration process.

> Operation results in exceeding quota limits of Core. Maximum allowed:
>   4, Current in use: 0, Additional requested: 6

[image]
Can you tell me what should I select so that I'm able to proceed (I tried to select minimum requirements, which went down from 10 to 6 quota)? I'm not too sure how the quota was counted. Is there anyone experienced the same issue before?

Answer (score 2):

You bumped into a quota limit enforced by Azure to prevent misuse.

You can increase the quota limit through a free **support request** in Azure. It took me 1 minute to get the approval, seems to be fully automated.

See here for more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/resource-manager-core-quotas-request

Comment: Important to note that in 2018 you can't request more cores if you have a free trial (you must have a pay-as-you-go subscription).